# Scroll into view by className to a paragraph that is a child of a child of an element - pure JS

Tags: javascript, parent-child, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname, js-scrollintoview

I want to scroll to a specific paragraph that is a child of a child of an element

Below is a simplified version of my html.

I want to scroll to the paragraph with the className of ticketType. There are more paragraphs in my actual code so I want to target it by className.

There will be other paragraphs with this className that I don't want to scroll to, so I need to specifically target (and scroll to) the paragraph with className of *ticketType* within the element that has an id of *ticket0.*

```
{this.state.tickets.map((e, i) => {
return (

    <div className = "content createTicket" id={`ticket${i}`} >

    <form key={i}>
        <p className="warning ticketType">{this.state.tickets[i].errors.ticketType}</p>
        <div className="group">
            <input
                required
                type="text"
                value={this.state.tickets[i].ticketType}
                onChange={event => this.changeTicketDetails(event, 'ticketType', i)}
                placeholder="Ticket Name eg. General Admission"
            />     
        </div>
    </form>

    )
```

})}

This code is scrolling to the parent div:

```
document.getElementById(`ticket0`).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
```

I am trying to get further options using:

```
document.getElementById(`ticket0`).children
```

but when I console.log this it isn't recognising the paragraph. I am getting:

```
HTMLCollection(2)
0: form
0: input
```

In CSS I could target it as `#ticket0 < .ticketType`

Is there something similar in Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that console output because [`parentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) returns an HTMLCollection and not a single element.

To achieve the desired behavior, you could try:
`document.querySelector('#ticket0 > .ticketType').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`

or put another way:
`document.getElementById('ticket0').getElementsByClassName('ticketType')[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`

or if you only care for the first child:
`document.getElementById('ticket0').firstElementChild.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`

or if you care about the `n`-th child:
`document.getElementById('ticket0').children[n].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`